# How to move styles folder to src folder in nextjs typescript with tailwindcss?

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

i'm using nextjs with typescript and tailwindcss. I want to move `styles` folder to `src` folder, i already added `baseUrl` with value `src` options in my `tsconfig.json` file, but I got an error like this :

```
    ./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/css-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/tailwindcss/tailwind.css
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
```

and how i move styles folder to src folder, i want to make my folder structure simpler. thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Object.fromEntries is not a function error when using chakra-ui and next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67550901/object-fromentries-is-not-a-function-error-when-using-chakra-ui-and-next-js)? `Object.fromEntries()` is only supported from Node.js v12 onwards.

Answer (score 27):

Delete the `.next` folder, then run the dev server again (with `npm run dev`).

This worked in my case. I'm guessing it's some kind of caching issue. Obviously you'll need to change your `tailwind.config.js` where the content should check `./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}` rather than `./pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}`.

Comment: Good find, it was being cached for me as well. Thank you for our answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after moving my files under `src` to clean up my root directory. I copied the config options for `tailwind.config.js` from [this example repo](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/blog.tailwindcss.com/blob/master/tailwind.config.js) from Tailwind Labs and found that it worked for me.

```
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './next.config.js'],
  },
  ...
```

Comment: This fixed for me in a 2023 Next js boiler plate, typescript, moving everything inside a `src` folder to make things easier, tailwindcss broke, this fixed, ty

Comment: This worked for me but I also get a warning: "The `purge`/`content` options have changed in Tailwind CSS v3.0. With this upgrade guide:  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#configure-content-sources

Answer (score 0):

config files must be stored in main root like next.config.js .
but style files can be stored in src directory.
read this doc:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

Comment: I already do, I keep the file as it, but still got an error.
I fixed the error by delete node_modules and reinstall it.
thanks for the answer :)