# Next.js can do npm run build locally, but cannot do npm run build when I am in my ssh console of my digital ocean droplet, TypeError: Object.fromEntr

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, digital-ocean

In my NextJS project I get the error below when I am doing npm run build on my to my Digital Ocean droplet through my ssh console, however, the npm run build command runs perfectly when I do it on my local machine and am not trying to push it to my Digital Ocean droplet... I have tried clearing the cache, removing node_modules, removing package-lock.json, I've even uninstalled various deprecated and unnecessary npm packages I had downloaded... please help!!!!

```
> next build

info  - Loaded env from /root/client-project/.env
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - Checking validity of types
info  - Creating an optimized production build .<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Skipped not serializable cache item 'Compilation/modules|/root/client-project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/css-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[6].use[1]!/root/client-project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[6].use[2]!/root/client-project/styles/globals.css': No serializer registered for Warning
<w> while serializing webpack/lib/cache/PackFileCacheStrategy.PackContentItems -> webpack/lib/NormalModule -> Array { 1 items } -> webpack/lib/ModuleWarning -> Warning
info  - Creating an optimized production build
warn  - Compiled with warnings

./styles/globals.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/css-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[6].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[6].use[2]!./styles/globals.css
Warning

(185:5) postcss-preset-env: You should write display: flex by final spec instead of display: box

info  - Collecting page data .REACT_APP_API http://137.184.83.226/api
info  - Collecting page data
[=   ] info  - Generating static pages (0/18)
Error occurred prerendering page "/blog". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:21)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at walkObject (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:31:10)
    at createThemeVars (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/create-theme-vars.js:19:25)
    at toCSSVar (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/to-css-var.js:26:64)

Error occurred prerendering page "/pricing". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:21)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at walkObject (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:31:10)
    at createThemeVars (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/create-theme-vars.js:19:25)
    at toCSSVar (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/to-css-var.js:26:64)

Error occurred prerendering page "/start-today-old". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:21)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at walkObject (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:31:10)
    at createThemeVars (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/create-theme-vars.js:19:25)
    at toCSSVar (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/to-css-var.js:26:64)

Error occurred prerendering page "/start-today". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:21)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at walkObject (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:31:10)
    at createThemeVars (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/create-theme-vars.js:19:25)
    at toCSSVar (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/to-css-var.js:26:64)

Error occurred prerendering page "/stripe/cancel". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:21)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at walkObject (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:31:10)
    at createThemeVars (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/create-theme-vars.js:19:25)
    at toCSSVar (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/to-css-var.js:26:64)

Error occurred prerendering page "/auth/login". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:21)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at walkObject (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:31:10)
    at createThemeVars (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/create-theme-vars.js:19:25)
    at toCSSVar (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/to-css-var.js:26:64)

Error occurred prerendering page "/auth/register". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:21)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at walkObject (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:31:10)
    at createThemeVars (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/create-theme-vars.js:19:25)
    at toCSSVar (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/to-css-var.js:26:64)
[==  ] info  - Generating static pages (7/18)
Error occurred prerendering page "/stripe/callback". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:21)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at walkObject (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:31:10)
    at createThemeVars (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/create-theme-vars.js:19:25)
    at toCSSVar (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/to-css-var.js:26:64)

Error occurred prerendering page "/stripe/success/[hotelId]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:21)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at walkObject (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:31:10)
    at createThemeVars (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/create-theme-vars.js:19:25)
    at toCSSVar (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/to-css-var.js:26:64)
[=== ] info  - Generating static pages (9/18)REACT_APP_API http://137.184.83.226/api

Error occurred prerendering page "/hotels/[hotelId]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:21)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at walkObject (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:31:10)
    at createThemeVars (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/create-theme-vars.js:19:25)
    at toCSSVar (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/to-css-var.js:26:64)

Error occurred prerendering page "/hotels/edit/[hotelId]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:21)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at walkObject (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:31:10)
    at createThemeVars (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/create-theme-vars.js:19:25)
    at toCSSVar (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/to-css-var.js:26:64)

Error occurred prerendering page "/hotels/new". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:21)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at walkObject (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:31:10)
    at createThemeVars (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/create-theme-vars.js:19:25)
    at toCSSVar (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/to-css-var.js:26:64)

Error occurred prerendering page "/index-old". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:21)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at walkObject (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:31:10)
    at createThemeVars (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/create-theme-vars.js:19:25)
    at toCSSVar (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/to-css-var.js:26:64)
[ ===] info  - Generating static pages (13/18)
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:21)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at walkObject (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:31:10)
    at createThemeVars (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/create-theme-vars.js:19:25)
    at toCSSVar (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/to-css-var.js:26:64)

Error occurred prerendering page "/profile/dashboard-seller". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:21)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at walkObject (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:31:10)
    at createThemeVars (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/create-theme-vars.js:19:25)
    at toCSSVar (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/to-css-var.js:26:64)

Error occurred prerendering page "/profile/dashboard". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:21)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at walkObject (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:31:10)
    at createThemeVars (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/create-theme-vars.js:19:25)
    at toCSSVar (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/to-css-var.js:26:64)

Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:21)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at walkObject (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:31:10)
    at createThemeVars (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/create-theme-vars.js:19:25)
    at toCSSVar (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/to-css-var.js:26:64)

Error occurred prerendering page "/500". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Object.fromEntries is not a function
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:21)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at /root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:24:22
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at inner (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:21:55)
    at walkObject (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/utils/dist/cjs/walk-object.js:31:10)
    at createThemeVars (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/create-theme-vars.js:19:25)
    at toCSSVar (/root/client-project/node_modules/@chakra-ui/styled-system/dist/cjs/create-theme-vars/to-css-var.js:26:64)
info  - Generating static pages (18/18)

> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /
    /404
    /500
    /auth/login
    /auth/register
    /blog
    /hotels/[hotelId]
    /hotels/edit/[hotelId]
    /hotels/new
    /index-old
    /pricing
    /profile/dashboard
    /profile/dashboard-seller
    /start-today
    /start-today-old
    /stripe/callback
    /stripe/cancel
    /stripe/success/[hotelId]
    at nextExportSpan.traceAsyncFn (/root/client-project/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:487:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object.fromEntries is not a function error when using chakra-ui and next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67550901/object-fromentries-is-not-a-function-error-when-using-chakra-ui-and-next-js)

Comment: No... it suggests that I update my node and assumes I have an old version of node but I'm currently running node v16.6.0 the latest version...

Comment: what version is on digitalocean.  it's unlikely to be node 16.  probably node 12.

Comment: @Jayen the version on digitalocean is v16.6.0, see the screenshot here: https://cln.sh/dGIwo5
I have even created a whole new github repo and cloned that one to deploy from digital ocean but i still get the same stupid error. i'm really pissed off right now i'm going crazy. please help

Comment: If you run `where node`, do you see multiple entries? If yes, try checking the versions of each of them. Could be that the `node` you're running is just first in the $PATH, but then one of the node's scripts has `#!/usr/bin/env node` (try running `/usr/bin/env node --version`) which refers to a different executable, perhaps one installed via the system's package manager.

Comment: did you try `npm ci` or `yarn`?